# The App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator::getUser() method must return a UserInterface. You returned Softonic\GraphQL\Response

Tags: symfony, authentication, graphql, symfony4

I'm trying to customize the login with a graphql query to load the User data and it shows me that error.

[image]

I use `php bin / console make: auth` and it works correctly when I query the $ user variable from MySQL but when I load the $ user variable from GRAPHQL it shows me that error.

This is the code:

```
public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
{

    if ($credentials["csrf_token"] != "") {
        $client = new GH();
        $headers = ['Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'];
        $result = $client->request('POST', 'https://graphql.clientecliente.com/get-token', [
            'json' => [
                'usuario' => $credentials["email"],
                'clave' => $credentials["password"]
            ]
        ]);
        $data = $result->getBody()->getContents();
        $objetodata=(json_decode($data));
        $token = $objetodata->token;
    }
    //Conexion servidor GraphQL
    $servidor = $this->params->get('enlace_graphql');
    //Codigo debe salir desde la base de datos
    $codigoAuth = $token;

    $options = [
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $codigoAuth,
        ],
    ];
    $client = \Softonic\GraphQL\ClientBuilder::build($servidor, $options);

$gpl1 = <<<'QUERY'
query ($limit: Int!, $offset: Int!, $CODIGO_USUARIO: String) {
    obt_usuarios(limit: $limit, offset: $offset, CODIGO_USUARIO: $CODIGO_USUARIO) {
      totalCount
      OBT_USUARIOS {
        CODIGO_USUARIO
        CLAVE_USUARIO
        CODIGO_EMPRESA
        CODIGO_CLIENTE
        CODIGO_PASAJERO
        ES_ADMINISTRADOR
      }
    }
  }
QUERY;

$variables1 = [
    'limit' => 10,
    'offset' => 0,
    'CODIGO_USUARIO' => $credentials["email"]
];

    //$user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Usuario::class)->findOneBy(['email' => $credentials['email']]);
    $user = $client->query($gpl1,$variables1);

    if (!$user) {
        // fail authentication with a custom error
        throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('El usuario no existe');
    }

    return $user;
}
```

Maybe, Anything idea?

---

Update.
Now create the custom user provider. I use this command: `php bin/console make:user;`

```
<?php
//src/Security/UserProvider.php
namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;

//Consulta API
use GuzzleHttp\Client as GH;
use GuzzleHttp\Pool;
//Consulta GraphQL
use Softonic\GraphQL;
use Softonic\GraphQL\Client;
use Softonic\GraphQL\ClientBuilder;
use function GuzzleHttp\json_decode;

class UserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * Symfony calls this method if you use features like switch_user
     * or remember_me.
     *
     * If you're not using these features, you do not need to implement
     * this method.
     *
     * @return UserInterface
     *
     * @throws UsernameNotFoundException if the user is not found
     */
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        $client = new GH();
            $headers = ['Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'];
            $result = $client->request('POST', 'https://graphql.cliente.com.ec/get-token', [
                'json' => [
                    'usuario' => 'test',
                    'clave' => 'test1234',

                ]
            ]);
            $data = $result->getBody()->getContents();
            $objetodata=(json_decode($data));
            //var_dump($objetodata->token);
            //exit;
            $token = $objetodata->token;

            $servidor = "https://graphql.cliente.com/graphql";         
            //Codigo debe salir desde la base de datos
            //$codigoAuth = $token;
            $codigoAuth= "12345678912345678mlvIjoiT0JUX0NjIxOTI1ODN9.8dNiZI6iZsYS0plVU0fuqFlhkTDSOt9OFy5B-WZiRmk";
            //var_dump($codigoAuth);
            //exit;
            //echo $codigoAuth; exit; 
        $options = [
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $codigoAuth,
            ],
        ];
        $client = \Softonic\GraphQL\ClientBuilder::build($servidor, $options);

$gpl1 = <<<'QUERY'
query ($limit: Int!, $offset: Int!, $CODIGO_USUARIO: String) {
    obt_usuarios(limit: $limit, offset: $offset, CODIGO_USUARIO: $CODIGO_USUARIO) {
      totalCount
      OBT_USUARIOS {
        CODIGO_USUARIO
        CLAVE_USUARIO
        CODIGO_EMPRESA
        CODIGO_CLIENTE
        CODIGO_PASAJERO
        ES_ADMINISTRADOR
      }
    }
  }
QUERY;

$variables1 = [
    'limit' => 10,
    'offset' => 0,
    'CODIGO_USUARIO' => 'test'
];

$user=$client->query($gpl1,$variables1);
//var_dump($user);exit;

        //$username=$user;
        return $user;      
        //throw new \Exception('TODO: fill in loadUserByUsername() inside '.__FILE__);
    }

    /**
     * Refreshes the user after being reloaded from the session.
     *
     * When a user is logged in, at the beginning of each request, the
     * User object is loaded from the session and then this method is
     * called. Your job is to make sure the user's data is still fresh by,
     * for example, re-querying for fresh User data.
     *
     * If your firewall is "stateless: true" (for a pure API), this
     * method is not called.
     *
     * @return UserInterface
     */
    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(sprintf('Invalid user class "%s".', get_class($user)));
        }

        // Return a User object after making sure its data is "fresh".
        // Or throw a UsernameNotFoundException if the user no longer exists.
        throw new \Exception('TODO: fill in refreshUser() inside '.__FILE__);
        return $this->loadUserByUsername($user->getUsername());

    }

    /**
     * Tells Symfony to use this provider for this User class.
     */
    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return User::class === $class;
    }
}
```

config/packages/security.yaml:

```
providers:
    app_user_provider:
        id: App\Security\UserProvider



firewalls:
    secured_area:
        anonymous: true
        form_login:
            login_path:  loginanterior
            check_path:  login_check
            default_target_path: index
            provider: app_user_provider
            remember_me: true

    logout:
        path:   logout
        target: index

    remember_me:
        secret:   '%kernel.secret%'
        lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
        path:     /
```

src/Security/User.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class User implements UserInterface
{
    private $email;

    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     */
    private $password;

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        // not needed when using the "bcrypt" algorithm in security.yaml
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }
}
```

However, after this it does not show me any errors or anything. Just go back to the login again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to map your `Softonic\GraphQL\Response` to your `User` model. This should be done in your [custom UserProvider](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html#creating-a-custom-user-provider) so `Authenticator` doesn't know where the user actually comes from. You can also look at [existing user providers code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/4.4/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User) for inspiration.

Comment: I create the user provider in the function loadUserByUsername at the end I make a return $ user does not show me any error just return to the login. Now update the question with the code.

Comment: You have to build `User` model from `Softonic\GraphQL\Response`:
`
$userData = $client->query($gpl1,$variables1)->getData();
$user = new User();
$user->setUsername($userData['username']);
[...]
return $user;
`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of [Ion Bazan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/851538/ion-bazan)
I understood that I had to make a custom UserProvider.

Final steps encoder correction

config/packages/security.yaml

```
encoders:
         App\Security\User:bcrypt
```

GraphQL result mapping on USER object by sending user, ROL and password (must be sent in the encryption correctly)

App/src/Security/UserProvider.php

```
$userData=$client->query($gpl1,$variables1)->getData();
//var_dump($userData);
$user = new User();
$user->setEmail($userData['obt_usuarios']["OBT_USUARIOS"][0]["CODIGO_USUARIO"]);
$user->setRoles(array("ROLE_USER"));
$user->setPassword('$2a$10$JSMRqSFX9Xm1gAbc/YzVcu5gETsPF8HJ3k5Zra/RZlx4IXfadwmW.');
return $user;      
}

    /**
     * Refreshes the user after being reloaded from the session.
     *
     * When a user is logged in, at the beginning of each request, the
     * User object is loaded from the session and then this method is
     * called. Your job is to make sure the user's data is still fresh by,
     * for example, re-querying for fresh User data.
     *
     * If your firewall is "stateless: true" (for a pure API), this
     * method is not called.
     *
     * @return UserInterface
     */
    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(sprintf('Invalid user class "%s".', get_class($user)));
        }

        // Return a User object after making sure its data is "fresh".
        // Or throw a UsernameNotFoundException if the user no longer exists.
        //throw new \Exception('TODO: fill in refreshUser() inside '.__FILE__);
        return $this->loadUserByUsername($user);

    }
```

With this finally it worked

[image]
[image]